# Cannot get Cordova text-to-speech plugin to work

Tags: cordova-plugins

I'm trying various plugins for TTS, including the one at https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts, but cannot get any to work. For this one, for example, according to the docs, its usage should be:

```
    TTS
    .speak('hello, world!', function () {
        alert('success');
    }, function (reason) {
        alert(reason);
    });
```

but I get 'TTS not defined'. Also tried 'navigator.TTS....' but still no good. Also I'm unsure whether I need to include the tts.js in the package; if so I get 'exports not defined'. If anyone is successfully using this plugin, please can you put me in the correct direction? Or if there's an alternative plugin that works, I could use that, but many TTS plugins on GitHub appear unsupported for 3-4 years.
BTW other plugins I am using  (e.g. geolocation) are working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have now solved this. I didn't have `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` in my index.html. This was also stopping 'onDeviceReady' from firing, which is how I came about solving it.
So it seems you need this script included for some plugins but not for others. How confusing.
Can I claim back my 50 bonus points for solving it myself? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer with keyword window

```
    window.TTS.speak({
        text: 'hello world!!',
        locale: 'en-GB',
        rate: 1.3
    }, function () {
        // Do Something after success
    }, function (reason) {
        // Handle the error case
    });
```

I tried the same way it worked for me.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work for me! TTS still undefined. Did you use tts.js from the repo? If so, how?

Comment: I added the plugin to root directory.

Comment: Is that somewhere different to any other plugins? Can you be more explicit, what's the path relative to the www folder for example? I'm using VS2015 which organises the plugins automatically, and all my other plugins work fine.