# Cordova Text to speech plguin

Tags: javascript, cordova, text-to-speech

I am new to Cordova and trying to implement [this](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts) TTS plugin, i cloned the plugin and added

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        window.TTS.speak({
            text: 'hello world!!',
            locale: 'en-GB',
            rate: 1.3
        },
        function () {
        },
        function (reason) {
        }, false);
</script>
```

in the body tag of index.html, but it's not working, could someone please help out?
I have referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37973147/cannot-get-cordova-text-to-speech-plugin-to-work/41050950?noredirect=1#comment69309431_41050950)
but still couldn't figure out

Comment: have you referenced the plugin in your app?

Comment: Thanks for the respone, I have tried `  window.plugins.TTS.speak` this as well but it did not work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what isn't working?  A couple questions that come to mind - is 'deviceready' being called?  Is window.TTS defined?

Comment: mine always takes the error, reason: "Missing Command Error"